# Async ajax call causing browser to freeze

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two different sets of `a` and `p` elements in my html page which are made as `display:none` by default.

At the end of the of the page I'm calling a function by sending their `ID`'s and some `values` to enable any one of them based on some conditions

1st set

```
 <a style="display:none;" id="ClickMe1">Click Me</a>
 <p class="button" id="Sorry1" style="display:none;">Sorry!</p>
```

2nd set

```
 <a style="display:none;" id="ClickMe2">Click Me</a>
 <p class="button" id="Sorry2" style="display:none;">Sorry!</p>
```

Function call

```
 <script>
        window.onload = function () {
           Initialize("ClickMe1", "Sorry1", "23,35");
           Initialize("ClickMe2", "Sorry2", "76,121");
        };
    </script>
```

Initialize function consists of `a ID`, `p ID` and set of values(it can contain `n` values) to check which element to enable

Javascript Function

```
function Initialize(ClickMeID, SorryID,Values) {
var valList = Values.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < valList.length; i++) {
        var paramts = "{'val':'" + valList[i] + "'}";
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/services/MyService.asmx/GetData",
            data: paramts,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                Status = response.d.toString();
            },
            error: function (response) {

            }
        });
            if (Status == "0") {
                    $('#' + SorryID).show();
                    return;
        }
    }
        $('#' + (ClickMeID).show();
}
```

In my function I'm splitting the comma seperated `Values` and looping through each value and making an `ajax` call to my service with `async:false`.

The response of success call is either `1` or `0`. If any of `Values` is `0` of a function call I want to display `p` element else `a` element of the sent `ID's`.

This function is working fine but when the function call is raised this is making the `browser` freeze until the execution of the function.

If I make `async: true` I'm not able to find out which set of buttons to enable and disable

How can I make prevent the browser from freezing.

Comment: your, ***sync*** ajax call you mean?

Comment: just FYI `async: false,` means it is synchronous not asynchronous - so it waits for that to return and appears to freeze

Comment: @KevinB Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss If I make asnc to true I'm not able to find out the results belong to which set of function call, which in turn causes me to which set to pair to enable

Comment: @durga and that's a problem that is far easier to solve than making sync ajax requests not block the browser (which is impossible)

Comment: @KevinB So what would be the solution for this to prevent from freezing

Comment: async: true, and re-factor your logic accordingly. yes, it's going to require rewriting most of the code you have up above. or, at least rearranging it.

Comment: @KevinB Can you help me out with some of the code, so I can go with that, to accomplish my requirements

Answer (score 4):

You should set

```
async: true
```

If it's not async, then it'll be blocking.

Also, if you're looping through many items, you should wrap each iteration in a setTimeout and make it async too.

---

Code samples

```
function click(e){
   var button = e.target;

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/accounts/save",
data : {
 accountID: 123,
name:"hello world"
},
      beforeSend: function(){
            //disable the button. 
      }
    }).always(function(){
        //enable the button
     })
```

}

here's an example of of setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
//do something
}, 3000); //3seconds
```

I would highly recommend, that you read up on jquery.Deferred and event loops.

Comment: If I make `async: true` I'm not able to find out which set of buttons to enable and disable. A sample code would be appreciated for `setTimeout`

Comment: To handle asynchronous behavior, you could leverage either 1) callbacks or 2) promises to work with your buttons. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: @KMC Should I do the ajax call in my `for` loop function and may I know what exactly the ajax call does

Comment: you can wrap the ajax call in a for loop.  As for what $.ajax is doing, i think you better start by reading the api. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @KMC Sorry for the late response, did u mean to set the timeout in the function call i.e., when I'm calling `Initialize` function

Comment: no. I'm saying that setTimeout is one way to make your webpage more responsive, since it's async. also, since I'm not familiar with the overall problem and app architecutre, it's up to you to determine if you need this or not.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not able to find out which set of buttons to enable and disable

Then that is your real issue.  You solved your problem with other code to cause a new problem.

I highly suggest reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Here is what I would do (since you tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) might as well.. actually fully use it).

```
<style>
  .is-hidden{ display: none; }
</style>


<div class="js-init-content" data-params="[{'val':23},{'val':35}]">
  <a class="is-hidden js-clickme">Click Me</a>
  <p class="button is-hidden js-sorry">Sorry!</p>
</div>

<div class="js-init-content" data-params="[{'val':76},{'val':121}]">
  <a class="is-hidden js-clickme">Click Me</a>
  <p class="button is-hidden js-sorry">Sorry!</p>
</div>


<script>
   // when the document is ready...
   $(document).ready(function(){

     // loop through each init-content item
     $(".js-init-content").each(function(){
       var $this = $(this);

       // get the data from the html element
       // jquery will return an array containing objects
       // because it's smart and cool like that
       var params = $this.data('params');

       var isAvailable = true;

       // loop through each param
       $.each(params, function(index, param){
         // stop loop and ajax calls if any previous ajax call failed
         if (!isAvailable) return false;

         // make an ajax call, param will be the object from the array
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/services/MyService.asmx/GetData",
           data: param,
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           // dataType: "json", -- jquery is smart it will figure it out
           // async: false,  -- Almost no reason to ever do this
        ).done(function(response){
            isAvailable = response.d.toString() != "0";
        }); // End Ajax-Done
     });  // End js-init-content.each

     var selector = isAvailable
       ? ".js-clickme"
       : ".js-sorry";

     $this.find(selector).removeClass("is-hidden");

   });  //  End doc-ready 
</script>
```

I encapsulated the data in the html, instead of hardcoding it in the javascript.  Fully used jQuery for loading and updating.

Comment: Removed my answer in favor of this one using classes, elimination of a function and adding the parameters to the data instead of the disconnected maintenance challenge.